# Proof formula for triangle: $b^2|BD| +a^2|AD| - c|CD|^2 = c|AD||BD|$

Tags: geometry, triangles

given is a triangle with corners A,B,C and corresponding sides a, b, c.

D is a point somewhere between A and B.

I have to proof:

$b^2|BD| +a^2|AD| - c|CD|^2 = c|AD||BD|$

Unfortunately I have no idea - I just tried with some pythagoras but only got nonsense.

So I'll be glad if you can give me a hint where to start, then I might get it :)

Kind regards!

Comment: FYI: This result is known as [Stewart's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewart%27s_theorem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need at the fondation of your work the cosinus rule (Al Kashi), which is the extension of Phytagoras.

That is (1) $$a^2=b^2+c^2-2bc \cos \angle A$$

The same way you have (2) $$|CD|^2=b^2+|AD|^2-2b|AD|\cos \angle A$$

Then

$b^2|BD| +a^2|AD| - c|CD|^2 =a^2|AD|+b^2(c-|AD|)-c(b^2+|AD|^2-2b|AD|\cos \angle A)$

$b^2|BD| +a^2|AD| - c|CD|^2 =(a^2-b^2)|AD|-c|AD|^2+2bc|AD|\cos \angle A$

$b^2|BD| +a^2|AD| - c|CD|^2 =(c^2-2bc\cos \angle A)|AD|-c|AD|^2+2bc|AD|\cos \angle A$

$b^2|BD| +a^2|AD| - c|CD|^2 =c|AD|(c-|AD|)=c|AD||BD|$

Comment: Thank you very much, still one question left: In the second line from below, is there a $|AD|$ missing in the $2bc\cos \angle A$?

Comment: @Vazrael Yes you are right. Edited! Thank you.